# Loop over a slice and exit if it does not exist

Tags: go

I am trying to create a loop that will do the following:

The loop will search in all items one by one of a slice:

1. if the letter does not exist continue to the next item of the loop.
2. If the letter exist, exit the loop.
3. if no matches in the slice, exit to the OS.

below is the code I am trying:

```
userDefinedletter := "g"
letters := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    for _, a := range letters{
        if a != userDefinedletter {
            continue
        } else if a == userDefinedletter {
            fmt.Printf("letter %s found. \n", userDefinedletter)
            break
        } else {
            fmt.Println("letter not found in the slice")
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a variable to false. In the loop, set the variable to true if the letter is found.  After the loop, check the variable to determine if the letter was found:

```
ok := false
for _, a := range letters {
    if a == userDefinedletter {
        ok = true
        break
    }
}

if ok {
    fmt.Printf("letter %s found. \n", userDefinedletter)
} else {
    fmt.Println("letter not found in the slice")
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're going in the right direction but for such a small function, you've done unnecessarily nesting which you could've avoided.

```golang
func present(slice []string, find string) bool {
        for _, s := range slice {
                if s == find {
                        return true
                }
        }
        return false
}

func main() {
        slice := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
        find := "g"
        if !present(slice, find) {
                os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Found: %s in slice: %v\n", find, slice)
}
```

Comment: This works well! thank you.. but is it possible to do it without a function ?

Comment: I'll leave the question to you. I just wanted to give you a direction. It's better if you find that out yourself!

Answer (score 1):

I think we can easy resolve your problem like this: Just check letter is in slide       or not and get the position when letter is included in slice.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    slice := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    find := "g"
    if pos := strings.Index(strings.Join(slice, ""), find); pos != -1 {
        fmt.Println("Slice does not contain letter")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Letter is in slice and position is: ", pos)
    }
}
```

You can quick test above code in this link online: https://play.golang.org/

Comment: Why are making it complicated for such a simple task. Concatenating the slice of string and using `strings.Index` to find the index is just the same as finding the element by looping but with extra operations. Why?

Comment: Why you need to do again a simple job when the library already did it?
Just need to understand what the library do and use it. My code is short and clean.
And you can re-implement the function when you reference it in github:
https://golang.org/src/strings/strings.go

Comment: You don't have to give references; everybody using Go knows the package is open-sourced. Point is you concatenated the strings and still defending the approach. Just to use a function from the strings package, you're doing unnecessary operations so that you can use `strings.Index`. NOTE: THIS IS A PLAIN LINEAR SEARCH.

Comment: I think that why my approach different from your, you can not make s.o thinking like you.
String already is a slice itself.

Comment: Being different doesn't mean right. The string is a slice of bytes but the string is immutable, you can read about it. So with every concatenation, you're making unnecessary allocations. I'm not arguing. I'm just saying that you're wrong and it's not the optimal way and you could have easily avoided by keeping it simple.

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.pl/view/9f2371e4 (PresentTwo is your function, PresentOne is the function that I wrote). Now see the benchmarking. Your code is taking 4x time, but use 8B every op, and makes 1 alloc/op where as the simpler function does it 0 B/op and 0 alloc/op. Please don't comment without benchmarking.

`BenchmarkPresentTwo-8        10967002               108 ns/op               8 B/op          1 allocs/op`
-------------------------------
`// BenchmarkPresentOne-8        35317174                32.7 ns/op             0 B/op          0 allocs/op`

Comment: Good job man, Tks for explain very detail for me.
Yes, you'r right, my approach make this problem complicated.
BTW, can you share me the doc for benchmarking golang.

Comment: Hey, you can refer this: https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go

Answer (score 0):

Because the letters are in sorted order, you can use [sort.SearchStrings](https://godoc.org/sort#SearchStrings):

```
i := sort.SearchStrings(letters, userDefinedletter)

if i < len(letters) && letters[i] == userDefinedletter {
    fmt.Printf("letter %s found. \n", userDefinedletter)

} else {
    fmt.Println("letter not found in the slice")
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: Don't assume it's already sorted if it's not mentioned.